# Kivy App size fixed in full screen windowed

Tags: python, kivy

I've made a windows app with Kivy and I want to set the size of the window to a fixed size which is full-screen windowed and I can't figure it out.
i've tried this method:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.size = (1920, 1080)
Window.fullscreen = True
```

It makes the app full screen but not full screen windowed. Does anyone have a solution for this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Config.set` determines the size of the window and should be indicated at the very beginning of the script. For more information check https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.config.html

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1920')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '1080')
```

Comment: please add explanation to your answer